# When does a wheel stop slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I am learning about friction in rolling motion in my high school physics classes and I don't have much intuition about this. If a wheel is rolling and slipping there is a dynamic friction involved, so if the wheel keeps rolling with the same acceleration will it be still slipping or what needs to happen so that the wheel starts moving without slipping?

Another part of my question is, when the wheel is moving without slipping (for eg on a slope), there must be some acceleration of the wheel, so will the point touching the ground still have zero velocity (like as if it was moving with constant speed) or can it have velocity that is not zero when it is not slipping?

Thanks.

Comment: If the wheel accelerates, then the static friction exerted by the ground must increase. The contact point of the wheel always has 0 velocity in pure rolling, since the linear acceleration of the point touching the ground is the same as the forward acceleration of the COM if the wheel is not slipping.

Comment: If you have any doubts, maybe check out Chapter 11 of Halliday's Fundamentals of Physics on the dynamics of rolling. Good textbook. And its free to download, just google it :)

Comment: Rolling with slipping is a somewhat subtle rotation problem.  In addition to reading the replies in this forum, you REALLY need to carefully read the example problem(s) in your physics book, and think about the solution to those problems until the underlying concepts make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The no slipping condition between the wheel and the ground is $v=r\omega$ where $v$ is the speed of the centre of mass of the wheel of radius $r$ and angular speed $\omega$.
If the wheel is on level ground and the no slipping condition is satisfied then the frictional force between the wheel and the ground is zero.

You can liken the motion of the wheel on the ground to a spinning wheel in outer space where the centre of mass of the wheel will continue moving in a straight line and the wheel will spin with a constant angular speed as there are no forces or torques acting on it.

On level ground suppose that $v> r\omega$ then the forces on the wheel will be as shown in the diagram on the left.

[image]

The dynamic frictional force $F$ acting left does two things to try to get to the no slip condition.
It reduces the magnitude of the translational speed and applies a torque $Fr$ on the wheel about the centre of mass $C$ which tries to increase the angular speed $\omega$.

If $v<r\omega$ (middle diagram) then the dynamic frictional force $F$ acting right tries to increase the speed of the centre of mass whilst at the same time trying to reduce the angular speed of the wheel.

On a slope (right hand diagram) if the no slip condition is satisfied there must be a static frictional force up along the slope to increase the angular speed whilst at the same time trying to reduce the rate of increase of the translational speed down the slope.

If you roll the wheel up the slope with the no slip condition satisfied the static frictional force is again directed up the slope.

Answer (score 1):

When the wheel is slipping, friction dissipate energy and the slipping velocity decrease.  The slipping stop when the slipping velocity is 0. You can easily compute this instant using the Coulomb law of friction.

If the wheel is not slipping, the slipping velocity is $0$ and so, by definition, the speed of the point of the wheel in contact with the ground is $0$ (if the ground is at rest).

Answer (score 1):

The friction force causes angular acceleration of the wheel.

The wheel stops slipping when the point in contact with the ground is not moving relative to the ground. That means the angular velocity and linear velocity of the wheel must be related by $v = r\omega$ where $r$ is the radius of the wheel.

Differentiating that equation, if there is no slipping the angular and linear accelerations must also be related by $a = r\dot\omega$.

The wheel will start to slip if the *static* friction between the wheel and the ground can not produce a big enough force to provide that angular acceleration.

If the wheel is already slipping, the *dynamic* friction acts in the direction to reduce the relative slipping velocity, i.e. the absolute value $|v - r\omega|$.